# Recursion $a_n=2a_{n+1}+8a_n$ with cardinality RxR

Tags: combinatorics

Recursion $a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}+8a_n$ has a characteristic polynomial $t^2-2t-8$ with roots $t=-2,4$ so the set is the series of  ${\alpha(-2)^n+\beta4^n}$ so why its cardinality  is RXR?

**Fixed a typo**

Was $a_n$. Changed to $a_{n+2}$

Comment: It is a sequence not a series.

Answer (score 1):

Each solution depends on a choice of an alpha and a beta. Since they can be any real number. So the cardinality of the solution is the cardinality of the set X = {(alpha, beta): alpha, beta in R }. Clearly /X/ = R*R as claimed.